# Allow BasicHttpBinding to process custom content types

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-binding, basichttpbinding

I have a client that does send Soap11 content, but with a different content type. It does not send `text/xml` but `application/some-custom-header`.

The client receives the following exception
Cannot process the message because the content type `'application/some-custom-header; charset=utf-8'` was not the expected type `'text/xml; charset=utf-8'`.

what do i need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I combined the encoding elements from the [Invoking a web service returning ISO-8859-1 encoded data with BizTalk 2010](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Invoking-a-web-service-9714e53e/sourcecode?fileId=75606&pathId=246027489) example, but replaced the `Read/WriteMessage` methods from the `CustomMessageEncoder` with the calls to a `MessageEncoder` retrieved from a `TextMessageEncodingBindingElement` and its `MessageEncoderFactory`.